# Tailwind no funciona cuando apago y vuelvo a prender la pc (instalacion CLI)

Tags: html, css, tailwind

ayer estuve haciendo una página a la cual le aplique estilos con Tailwind (seguí la instalación de Tailwind por CLI) y todo andaba perfecto, los estilos se aplicaban perfectamente. Hoy vuelvo a prender mi PC para seguir con el proyecto y hay estilos que no se aplican:

```html
<section>
        <div class="min-h-screen">
          <div
            class="flex-auto pt-0 md:pt-[18rem] mb-20 text-center"
            data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-duration="2500"
          >
            <h2 class="text-3xl font-thin">Hi, My name is</h2>
            <h1 class="text-6xl font-bold mb-5 text-red-500">
              Firstname Lastname
            </h1>
            <h2 class="text-2xl pl-1.5 font-thin">And I'm a Web Developer</h2>
          </div>
          <!-- mas codigo -->
        </div>
</section>
```

Me di cuenta de este error cuando intente que la página sea responsive, agregue un md:pt-[18rem] para que cuando supere los 768px le agregue al contener un padding top de 18rem, pero este nunca se aplicaba. Mis archivos de configuración de tailwind siguen igual que siempre:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es algo que me rompio la cabeza un monton, no se si pueda ayudarte.

Personalmente uso Tailwind con React y Postcss, en la pagina esta el tutorial para instalar Posstcss.

Las clases son iguales, prueba a volver a hacer el proceso pero esta vez con Postcss a ver si funciona

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), saludos.

Comment: Hola josea17m, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario a fin de evitar votos negativos, si no hay una pregunta bien formulada, hay una alta probabilidad de que tu respuesta esté equivocada, espera que se corrija la pregunta antes de contestar, es una sugerencia.

Comment: Es que no puedo comentar xD, y tecnicamente le di una respuesta, fue reinstalar usando otro paquete